# Dice Simulator hickup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dice

I am buidling a dice rolling simulator in Visual Studio Community 2015 and have come up against an odd glitch. I can get the bottom side value through a random number and even get the opposite top side value of the dice.
My problem is that sometimes when getting the value for the front side of the dice it gives me the same number as either the top or bottom sides.
I haven't been coding for too long but I would assume that the nested if statements I have entered shoud force the front dice side value to be "fetched" again if the value is the same as either the top or bottom side values.

In the section of the code where it is trying to determine the value of the front side of the dice it seems as if it ignores the nested "if" statements.
I have run the program and once about every 15 rolls it throws a value that I try to filter out. Rolls where the top side values are 1 or 6 don't cause issues, it is only when I need it to reroll on the numbers 2 through 5.

Here is my code. I admit, it is kind of sloppy but with time I want to trim it down and make it streamlined.

```
       //Dice Facings
        //This is a list of all of the possible dice facings on a 6-sided dice (also know as a D6)
        //Array Structure: Top/Right/Back/Front/Left/Bottom
        int[,] DiceCombos = { 
            {1,2,3,4,5,6}, {1,4,2,5,3,6}, {1,5,4,3,2,6}, {1,3,5,2,4,6}, 
            {2,6,3,4,1,5}, {2,3,1,6,4,5}, {2,1,4,3,6,5}, {2,4,6,1,3,5},
            {3,2,6,1,5,4}, {3,1,2,5,6,4}, {3,5,1,6,2,4}, {3,6,5,2,1,4},
            {4,2,1,6,5,3}, {4,1,5,2,6,3}, {4,5,6,1,2,3}, {4,6,2,5,1,3},
            {5,1,3,4,6,2}, {5,3,6,1,4,2}, {5,6,4,3,1,2}, {5,4,1,6,3,2},
            {6,5,4,3,2,1}, {6,4,2,5,3,1}, {6,2,3,4,5,1}, {6,3,5,2,4,1}
        };

        //To be able to use this information, once the dice are rolled.
        //Need a way to determine how the dice landed (facing wise). To do this we run a random number from 1-6 against the Front value of the dice.
        //Once a matching number is found for the FSide (Front Side) value, 
        //the program will look up the facing in a built in database (tiny one as you can tell here).
        //Say the value of Rolled = 4 (BoSide) and through random number generation, the value of FSide = 2.
        //Then the program would know that LSide (Left Side) = 1 and RSide (Right Side) = 6
        //

        // Get the Top Facing side based on the value of BoSide

        // Get a Random number for the Front Facing side.

        //Example of how to show facing based on strength of the roll 
        // Soft roll
        // NOFaces==3 ; number of times to show a top number (3rd value = final)
        // Generate random number between 1-6: Pass to BoSide and get TSide value. Show TSide value.
        // Repeat two more times, the final time being the value the dice ends up on.

        //Variables to think about when the dice are rolling.
        //When rolling the dice to the right the numbers roll from the front and from the left
        //When rolling the dice to the left the numbers roll from the front and from the right
        //Giving the dice a backspin causes the numbers to roll back a tick or two before rolling forward
        //      Soft roll: First facing goes from the back to the front.
        //      Regular roll: First 2 facings go backwards.
        //      Hard roll: Up to 5 facings go backwards.

        //On each "tick" of a roll check these things...
        //Faces; where are the numbers located on the dice.
        //Direction; which numbers will be checked for this time.
        //Corners

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Basic check for Bottom Facing side of dice
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int BoSide = new int();
        int TopSide = new int();
        BoSide = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);

        // Get the value for TopSide
        if (BoSide == 1) { TopSide = 6;}  
        if (BoSide == 2) { TopSide = 5;}
        if (BoSide == 3) { TopSide = 4;}
        if (BoSide == 4) { TopSide = 3;}
        if (BoSide == 5) { TopSide = 2;}
        if (BoSide == 6) { TopSide = 1;}
        else;

        //Get the value for FSide
        int FSide = new int();
        if (TopSide == 1)
        {
            FSide = rnd.Next(2, 5 + 1);
        }
        if (TopSide == 2)
        {
            FSide = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            if (FSide == 2)
            {
                FSide = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            }
            if (FSide == 5)
            {
                FSide = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            }
        }
        if (TopSide == 3)
        {
            FSide = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            if (FSide == 3)
            {
                FSide = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            }
            if (FSide == 4)
            {
                FSide = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            }
        }
        if (TopSide == 4)
        {
            FSide = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            if (FSide == 3)
            {
                FSide = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            }
            if (FSide == 4)
            {
                FSide = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            }
        }
        if (TopSide == 5)
        {
            FSide = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            if (FSide == 5)
            {
                FSide = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            }
            if (FSide == 2)
            {
                FSide = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            }
        }
        if (TopSide == 6)
        {
            FSide = rnd.Next(2, 5 + 1);
        }

        // Get the Left, Back and Right Side Numbers
        int RSide = new int();
        int LSide = new int();
        int BSide = new int();
        if (TopSide == 1)
        {
            if (FSide == 2)
            {
                RSide = 3; BSide = 5; LSide = 4;
            }
            if (FSide == 3)
            {
                RSide = 5; BSide = 4; LSide = 2;
            }
            if (FSide == 4)
            {
                RSide = 2; BSide = 3; LSide = 5;
            }
            if (FSide == 5)
            {
                RSide = 4; BSide = 2; LSide = 3;
            }
        }
        if (TopSide == 2)
        {
            if (FSide == 1)
            {
                RSide = 4; BSide = 6; LSide = 3;
            }
            if (FSide == 3)
            {
                RSide = 1; BSide = 4; LSide = 6;
            }
            if (FSide == 4)
            {
                RSide = 6; BSide = 3; LSide = 1;
            }
            if (FSide == 6)
            {
                RSide = 3; BSide = 1; LSide = 4;
            }
        }
        if (TopSide == 3)
        {
            if (FSide == 1)
            {
                RSide = 2; BSide = 6; LSide = 5;
            }
            if (FSide == 2)
            {
                RSide = 6; BSide = 5; LSide = 1;
            }
            if (FSide == 5)
            {
                RSide = 1; BSide = 2; LSide = 6;
            }
            if (FSide == 6)
            {
                RSide = 5; BSide = 1; LSide = 2;
            }
        }
        if (TopSide == 4)
        {
            if (FSide == 1)
            {
                RSide = 5; BSide = 6; LSide = 2;
            }
            if (FSide == 2)
            {
                RSide = 1; BSide = 5; LSide = 6;
            }
            if (FSide == 5)
            {
                RSide = 6; BSide = 2; LSide = 1;
            }
            if (FSide == 6)
            {
                RSide = 5; BSide = 1; LSide = 2;
            }
        }
        if (TopSide == 5)
        {
            if (FSide == 1)
            {
                RSide = 3; BSide = 6; LSide = 4;
            }
            if (FSide == 3)
            {
                RSide = 6; BSide = 4; LSide = 1;
            }
            if (FSide == 4)
            {
                RSide = 1; BSide = 3; LSide = 6;
            }
            if (FSide == 6)
            {
                RSide = 4; BSide = 1; LSide = 3;
            }
        }
        if (TopSide == 6)
        {
            if (FSide == 2)
            {
                RSide = 3; BSide = 5; LSide = 4;
            }
            if (FSide == 3)
            {
                RSide = 5; BSide = 4; LSide = 2;
            }
            if (FSide == 4)
            {
                RSide = 2; BSide = 3; LSide = 5;
            }
            if (FSide == 5)
            {
                RSide = 4; BSide = 2; LSide = 3;
            }
        }
        // Show Values
        label5.Text = Convert.ToString(BoSide);
        label17.Text = Convert.ToString(BoSide);
        label7.Text = Convert.ToString(TopSide);
        label26.Text = Convert.ToString(TopSide);
        label14.Text = Convert.ToString(FSide);
        label28.Text = Convert.ToString(FSide);
        label15.Text = Convert.ToString(LSide);
        label13.Text = Convert.ToString(BSide);
        label12.Text = Convert.ToString(RSide);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your design is needlessly complicated.**

There are 24 possible orientations of the die.  You have already stored these in a data structure.

All you need to do is make a single call to `rnd()`, and select the corresponding element of the data structure, set `TopSide()` to the first element in the array that you have selected, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood it fully, but aren't u making it far more complex than it should really be? You should just get the value of Front face through a `Random` call. All other faces will automatically get **locked**, no? So you don't need to use `Random` again to get the values of other sides. You just need to create a `Dictionary<int, int[]>` that will have 6 elements in it (one KEY for each value of FRONT face, while the VALUE member will have the values of other 5 faces). You then simply locate the values of other values through the `Dictionary` key.

```
//create a Dictionary
var Dic = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();

//Add all 6 possible configs
Dic.Add(1, {1,2,3,4,5,6});
Dic.Add(2, {2,6,3,4,1,5});
Dic.Add(3, {3,2,6,1,5,4});
Dic.Add(4, {4,2,1,6,5,3});    
Dic.Add(5, {5,1,3,4,6,2});
Dic.Add(6, {6,5,4,3,2,1});

//do a random
Random r = new Random();
var Front = r.Next(1, 6 + 1);

//Get your Dice's config
var DiceConfig = Dic[Front];
```